# How to pass a variable to a query in Oracle stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I wrote a simple oracle stored procedure to fetch some data using a `SYS_REFCURSOR`. In my query I have a `WHERE` clause. I want to pass a parameter to the where clause. Here what I tried,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GETCUSTOMER(customer_code IN CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_CODE%TYPE, customer_names OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
 IS
BEGIN

OPEN customer_names FOR
SELECT
  *
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE CUSTOMER_CODE = customer_code;

END;
/
```

I executed this using spring jdbcTemplate. This is not working as expected. This fetches all the data in the `CUSTOMER` table.

Is there a special way to pass a parameter in to a `WHERE` clause? How may I fix this?

Comment: You syntax is correct, it should work.

Comment: Nope. when i'm running the query with query browser, it fetches only one result(correct result). But when i'm running it using the procedure it fetches all the table data.

Comment: Do you want to return the all columns of a customer or customer_name for a given customer code?

Comment: Oh, just seen the problem: `WHERE CUSTOMER_CODE = customer_code`.  SQL is not case-sensitive, so this will return every row because `customer_code` is assumed to refer to the column name not the parameter.  Easiest solution is to rename parameter to e.g. `p_customer_code` - that is pretty much the standard convention.  Another way would be `customer_code = getcustomer.customer_code`.

Comment: @TonyAndrews -- the p_ prefix is indeed widely used, but it's horrible, and most Oracle programmers aren't even aware that there's an alternative. You don't see it used in Oracle's own stored procedures and functions, and I think there's a reason for that.

Comment: @DavidAldridge - yes it isn't great - it tacitly assumes another convention is that column names never begin with "P_"!

Comment: @TonyAndrews and it also leads to other monstrosities such as g_ for "global" variables and "l_" for local variables.

Comment: @DavidAldridge - I've never known anything else!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just prefix the variable with the procedure name.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GETCUSTOMER(customer_code IN CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_CODE%TYPE, customer_names OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
 IS
BEGIN

OPEN customer_names FOR
SELECT
  *
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE CUSTOMER_CODE = GETCUSTOMER.customer_code;

END;
/
```